# How to retrive the original labels in a K-Means clustering : PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, databricks

I am using the **pyspark.ml.clustering** library to train a K-Means clustering model. I am able to train it and obtain the cluster centres, here is the piece of code attached below. I am obtaining the centres as a list (ref to the code), my task is that I want to obtain the original data labels for each column. Any help is appreciated!

I have used the StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, StandardScalar and VectorAssembler as feature engineering before training the model on the normalized features column.

```
centers = model.clusterCenters()
ClusterCenter = [x.tolist() for x in centers] 
display(ClusterCenter)
```

Comment: The column names are in the `inputCols` parameter to `VectorAssembler`.

Comment: after you fit the model run the ```.transform()``` on the test set and then verify via ```preds_df.printSchema()``` ... those FE cols will appended